# Cell size not changing dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I am creating a Iphone app with UITableView. In that I want to change the cell size with respect to text. I used the following code. But it fails.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//    CGSize screenSize = screenBounds.size;

NSStringDrawingContext *ctx = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
NSAttributedString *aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[message objectAtIndex:0]];
UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[calculationView setAttributedText:aString];
CGRect textRect = [calculationView.text boundingRectWithSize:self.view.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:calculationView.font} context:ctx];
//    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, FLT_MAX)];
return textRect.size.height;
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
[cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gg.jpg"];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[message objectAtIndex:0], indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to NSLog() the height of the textRect.size.height value to see what height you're getting. What are you seeing visually, is your cell height correctly spaced but the text is single line? If yes, try setting cell.textLabel.numberOfRows = 0; Otherwise, If you're open to alternative method, I wrote a demo app using Autolayout here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478825/conflicting-constraints-in-ios-7-uitableviewcell-with-autolayout/24485396#24485396

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get text size.. and according this size you can set cell height.. like this example

```
  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


            CGSize contsize={260.00f,3000.00f};
            UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:15.0];

            NSString *strt11=@"comment_text"

            CGSize fontSize=[test sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:contsize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];        
            if (fontSize.height>22)
                return fontSize.height+60.0f;

            return 80.0f;
    }
```

and also put this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method for set uilabel height..

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSString *text = [array_loaddata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:cellText
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: cellFont
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){kWIDTH_FOR_MESSAGE_LABEL, MAXFLOAT}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];


    return rect.size.height + 75;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row] ;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        NSString *text = [array_loaddata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:cellText
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: cellFont
     }];
    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){kWIDTH_FOR_MESSAGE_LABEL, MAXFLOAT}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];  
      UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46, 0,kWIDTH_FOR_MESSAGE_LABEL, rect.size.height)];
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        label.text = (text ? text : @"");
        label.font = font;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [label release];


    }
```

Comment: the above only increases the cell height the text is not showing fully.

Comment: for kWIDTH_FOR_MESSAGE_LABEL give your required label width.

Answer (score 0):

As Simple as that :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```